# Pulp taking too much time to solve

Tags: python, linear-algebra, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to pack items in trucks using Pulp Solver, it works fine when the quantity of items is small(i.e. <25) but when I increase the quantity to even 30-32 it takes forever to solve.

This is the code of pulp solver:

```
def allocator(item_mass, item_vol, truck_mass, truck_vol, truck_cost, id_series):
    n_items = len(item_vol)
    set_items = range(n_items)
    n_trucks = len(truck_cost)
    set_trucks = range(n_trucks)


    y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('truckUsed', set_trucks,
        lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)

    x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('itemInTruck', (set_items, set_trucks), 
        lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)

    # Model formulation
    prob = LpProblem("Truck allocation problem", LpMinimize)

    # Objective
    prob += lpSum([truck_cost[i] * y[i] for i in set_trucks])
    # Constraints
    for j in set_items:
        # Every item must be taken in one truck
        prob += lpSum([x[j][i] for i in set_trucks]) == 1

    for i in set_trucks:
        # Respect the mass constraint of trucks
        prob += lpSum([item_mass[j] * x[j][i] for j in set_items]) <= truck_mass[i]*y[i]

        # Respect the volume constraint of trucks
        prob += lpSum([item_vol[j] * x[j][i] for j in set_items]) <= truck_vol[i]*y[i]
    # Ensure y variables have to be set to make use of x variables:
    for j in set_items:
        for i in set_trucks:
            x[j][i] <= y[i]

    s = id_series  # id_series

    prob.solve()
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here's the [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ih8Y8baIRQ3Z8SIXOzGHIeorcLcK1DWn?usp=sharing) to the jupyter notebook and test files.

Comment: What solver did you use? First thing I would try is using a better solver.

Comment: I used the PulP solver

Comment: You are mistaken. PuLP is not a solver. It is a modeling tool that can use different solvers. See the documentation.

Comment: Pardon me but I am fairly new to this.. I have attached the code with this can you please take a look and help ?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I checked the solvers I have it says `* Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.PULP_CBC_CMD'> passed.
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.CPLEX_DLL'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.CPLEX_CMD'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.CPLEX_PY'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.COIN_CMD'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.COINMP_DLL'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GLPK_CMD'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.XPRESS'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GUROBI'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GUROBI_CMD'> unavailable`

Comment: One other thing, which may or may not be affecting your run time but is almost certainly affecting the solution *correctness* is that the line near the end, `x[j][i] <= y[i]`, should be `prob += x[j][i] <= y[i]`.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 could you please explain a little as to why it should be `prob += x[j][i] <= y[i]`

Comment: That's just how you add a constraint to the model in PuLP, just like in your lines like `prob += lpSum([x[j][i] for i in set_trucks]) == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you are using CBC, an open-source MIP solver.
2 possible approaches:

1. use a better solver such as CPLEX or GUROBI (commercials, but free for students and academics). PuLP has an API for both of them.
2. Do you need an optimal solution? If this is not the case, put a time limit.

Example:

```
prob.solve(pulp.COIN(maxSeconds=your_time_limit))
```

Comment: I checked for all the solvers I have by `pulp.pulpTestAll()` and it returns `* Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.PULP_CBC_CMD'> passed.
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.CPLEX_DLL'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.CPLEX_CMD'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.CPLEX_PY'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.COIN_CMD'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.COINMP_DLL'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GLPK_CMD'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.XPRESS'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GUROBI'> unavailable
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GUROBI_CMD'> unavailable`

Comment: You need to download the solver you would like to install and install it. For GLPK, you can do `apt-get install glpk-utils`. For Cplex and Gurobi you need to go through their websites.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem is too symetrical. i.e. There are a multiple trucks that are exactly the same.

When this happens CBC can spend along time finding the 'Best' solution.

You have 2 options here:

- set a time limit or bound gap, which will exit the solve process early but still return a "good" solution.
- Set a secondary cost function to make things less symmetrical, i.e. prefer that lowest numbered items are assigned to lowest numbered trucks. This symmetry happens automatically in commercial solvers like gurobi.

Comment: Instead of giving the quantity of trucks, I replicated them in the CSV itself such that it never finds shortage of trucks.